# Writing MD5 Hash to file is littered with extraneous characters

Tags: vb.net

### Update:

I made some edits to clean up remnants of efforts that weren't helping.

I understood previously that "something" is occurring during the file-write process and that it's something that I personally am not perceiving.

Thanks to Plutonix in the comments, I know that the problem is in how I'm handling this but I don't understand exactly how to do it properly and research isn't turning anything up.

---

I'm attempting to write a file that must be then prefixed with an md5 checksum of itself

The result should be

```
[hash of "the brown fox"]the brown fox
```

In the example file I'm testing on, this is the hash I want to reproduce. Viewing in UTF-8 or in Hex reveals that these are the only characters within

```
¶ Âè¶“Naþ¼Wô}¾}
```

VB.net Debug.print produces exactly this

```
Hash.tostring: ¶ Âè¶“Naþ¼Wô}¾}
hash.length: 16
hash.tostring.length: 16
utf8hash.length: 28 -- I think this is part of the problem?
```

The file writes, as seen in UTF-8 or a Hex Editor

```
Â¶Â Ã‚Ã¨Â¶â€œNaÃ¾Â¼WÃ´}ÂÂ¾}
```

This is one variant of most of my efforts

```
    Dim HashMaker As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim HashBytes As Byte() = HashMaker.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()))
    Dim Hash As New StringBuilder()
    For hx = 0 To HashBytes.Length - 1
        Hash.Append(Chr(HashBytes(hx)))
    Next

    Dim HashMaker As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim HashBytes As Byte() = HashMaker.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()))
    Dim Hash As New StringBuilder()
    For hx = 0 To HashBytes.Length - 1
        Hash.Append(Chr(HashBytes(hx)))
    Next

    Debug.Print(Hash.ToString())

    Dim fHeader As Byte() = New Byte(7) {}
    Array.Copy(b, fHeader, 8)

    Dim utf8hash As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Hash.ToString())
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fname & "_long", "")
    Dim s As New System.IO.FileStream(fname & "_long", System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite)
    s.Write(b, 0, 8)
    s.Write(utf8hash, 0, utf8hash.Length)
    s.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), 0, sb.Length)
    s.Close()
```

I've tried an alternate method

```
        Dim utf8 As String = ""
        For hx = 0 To HashBytes.Length - 1
            Hash.Append(Chr(HashBytes(hx)))
            utf8 &= Chr(HashBytes(hx))
        Next

        Dim fHeader As Byte() = New Byte(7) {}
        Array.Copy(b, fHeader, 8)

        Dim utf8hash As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Hash.ToString())
        Debug.Print("Hash.tostring: " & Hash.ToString())
        Debug.Print("hash.length: " & Hash.Length)
        Debug.Print("hash.tostring.length: " & Hash.ToString.Length)
        Debug.Print("utf8hash.length: " & utf8.Length)
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fname & "_long", "")
        Dim s As New System.IO.FileStream(fname & "_long", System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite)
        s.Write(b, 0, 8)
        s.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(utf8), 0, 16)
        s.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), 0, sb.Length)
```

### As for a Self-contained example:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class Form1
    Private Function TestWrite()
        Dim book As Integer = 5, row As Integer = 5
        Dim fname As String = "c:\programtestFile.dat"
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder

        Dim HashMaker As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim HashBytes As Byte() = HashMaker.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"))
        Dim Hash As New StringBuilder()

        For hx = 0 To HashBytes.Length - 1
            Hash.Append(Chr(HashBytes(hx)))
        Next

        Debug.Print(Hash.ToString)

        Dim utf8hash As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Hash.ToString())
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fname & "_long", "")
        Dim s As New System.IO.FileStream(fname & "_long", System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite)
        's.Write(b, 0, 8)
        s.Write(utf8hash, 0, utf8hash.Length)
        's.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), 0, sb.Length)
        s.Close()
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TestWrite()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The code below prints this this to debug window

```
    kÍF!ÓsÊÞNƒ&'´ö (it is prefixed by a tab, part of the computed hash)
```

But writes this to the file (as can be seen in a hex editor or setting the Encoding to UTF-8

```
ÂkÃF!Ã“sÃŠÃžNÆ’&'Â´Ã¶
```

Comment: tl;dr  The hash output is binary.  The proper way to express it as string would be as a base64 string (especially if you will use it to later validate) or encode it as Hex

Comment: You should turn on Option Strict.  There are plenty of odd ball conversion in that code.  Example: `"&H01"` is not a byte, but a string

Comment: @Plutonix My live code has nothing like the `&H01`. I was creating a self-contained example quickly. It turned out in order to replicate the result, I didn't need that byte array but I forgot to remove it. Apologies.

Comment: The point remains, `Chr(HashBytes(hx)` is the wrong way to encode binary data, and you ought not "clean" it if you plan to use it to verify the hash.

Comment: Hey, I was having trouble figuring out what to do. I was writing the hash to file and getting strange characters. I tried "cleaning" those characters out because the hash I'm trying to match doesn't have them, only to find out that they were occurring because I was doing something wrong. I knew I had to be doing something wrong or missing a step but had a tremendous trouble figuring out what that was. Anyway, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out what I needed to do is assemble all the Bytes into a single Byte Array like so.

The first 8 bytes are a sort of header. The next 16 are an MD5 checksum of the remaining bytes.

I hope this helps someone.

```
Dim FileBytes(8 + HashBytes.Length + StringBytes.Length - 1) As Byte
Array.Copy(b, 0, FileBytes, 0, 8)
Array.Copy(HashBytes, 0, FileBytes, 8, 16)
Array.Copy(StringBytes, 0, FileBytes, 24, StringBytes.Length)
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fname, FileBytes)
```